# When mounting an azure file share in a web app I get a state of InvalidCredentials

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a File Share setup in a Storage Account. When I try to mount it in my Web App I get the following response:

```
  "nexport-shared": {
    "accessKey": "hidden==",
    "accountName": "hidden",
    "mountPath": "\\\\nexportshared",
    "shareName": "nexportcampusbetashare",
    "state": "InvalidCredentials",
    "type": "AzureFiles"
  }
```

I am using the az CLI command below :

```
az webapp config storage-account add --resource-group "GROUPNAME" --name "WEBAPPNAME" --custom-id nexport-shared --storage-typeAzureFiles --share-name nexportcampusbetashare --account-name STORAGEACCOUNT --access-key "hidden==" --mount-path "\\nexportshared" --verbose --debug
```

When I run 'az webapp config list' it shows up in the list but still with InvalidCredentials

Comment: Does the issue still exist? If you have found a solution, please share it, thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue; linking my post here in case that helps others in future: https://serverfault.com/questions/1086197/mounting-azure-files-in-azure-app-service

Comment: For your issue, your mount path is formatted like a UNC path; but normally for Linux containers it would look something like `"mountPath": "/nexportshared"`; or for Windows: `"mountPath": "c:\\nexportshared"`.  Hopefully that's some help, if this is still an issue...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to turn off or modify the firewall on the storage account for the Azure-Cli and the App Service to be able to see it.

Comment: This helped me, specifically: Networking -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> Public network access -> Enabled from all networks

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that you have input an invalid key or storage account to mount the Azure files. Correcting these parameters fixes this issue for me.

[image]

Fixed as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting same response and file share is working as expected.
Also I just found an issue created about this, seems to be an error in the response message from the API:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21571